# Java Extract key values from nested json

Tags: java, api, gson, rest-assured

i do have following JSON and i am trying to extract objects inside result

```
{
   "status":true,
   "results":{
      "type1":{
         "id":"type1"
      },
      "type2":{
         "id":"type2"
      }
   }
}
```

Desired output is

```
type1,type2
```

I am using Gson for serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you should be doing when using gson

1. get keys of the json objects which are inside "results" alone
2. get it as json object which has keys and values
3. collect the entry set our of the JSON
4. create an iterator so that later you can extract the keys

Here is code that does the same job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        String json = "{\r\n" + 
                "   \"status\":true,\r\n" + 
                "   \"results\":{\r\n" + 
                "      \"type1\":{\r\n" + 
                "         \"id\":\"type1\"\r\n" + 
                "      },\r\n" + 
                "      \"type2\":{\r\n" + 
                "         \"id\":\"type2\"\r\n" + 
                "      }\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "}";
        
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject obj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
        
        //get keys of the json objects which are inside "results" alone
        //get it as json object which has keys and values
        //collect the entry set our of the JSON
        //create an iterator so that later you can extract the keys
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = obj.get("results")
                                                            .getAsJsonObject()
                                                            .entrySet()
                                                            .iterator();
        
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            //here you will get the keys like - type1 and type2
            System.out.println(iterator.next().getKey());
        }
    
    }
```

**Code Edit:** What @fluffy pointed makes complete sense. Made the change

Comment: You don't need to instantiate `Gson` here. `Gson` also applies deserialization one doesn't need here. `JsonParser` is a better choice.